# FFmpeg Padding Video is not transparent

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg-python` as a wrapper around `ffmpeg`.

I have a `video.mp4` which I am padding using:

```
import ffmpeg

v = ffmpeg.input('video.mp4')
kwargs = {
      'w':'100', 
      'h':'100', 
      'x':'10', 
      'y':'10', 
      'color':'black@0'}
v_pad = ffmpeg.filter(v, filter_name='pad', **kwargs)
v_pad.output('out.mp4').run()
```

However, the background is just black. How can I make it transparent?

Comment: The issue is alpha channel (aka: transparency) settings and support. And not all video codecs support it. I don’t know how to handle that myself, but one of the FFmpeg pros who check this site out regularly should be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an encoder that supports alpha channel such as libvpx-vp9.

To check alpha support see the output of `ffmpeg -h encoder=<encoder name>`, refer to `Supported pixel formats`, and look for "`a`" in the results, such as `yuva420p`.

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]format=yuva420p,pad=iw+200:ih+200:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:black@0" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0 output.webm
```

For more info on this particular encoder see [FFmpeg Wiki: VP9](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9).

If it doesn't work make sure your player or browser supports it as well: `ffmpeg` may have done its job properly but the player itself could be the issue.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. However, is it expected to have such long rendering? It went from 0 seconds, to > 2 mins for this codec.

Comment: @GRS Yes. libvpx-vp9 is slow.

Comment: And `libx264` doesn't for some reason support alpha channel. Although it should from https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/46l4zj/codecs_that_support_transparency/

Comment: @GRS That comment by ichenye can be read incorrectly. By "transparent" they meant that it can be "visually lossless" and says nothing regarding alpha. Seems they were confused as to what the OP was asking. The comment by Jdcampbell only provides (incorrect) hearsay and no proof. libx264 does not support alpha and I am unaware of any H.264 encoder that does.